# How is this user still around?

Tags: support, status-completed, chat, abuse

Just flagged a drive by abuse from [this guy](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/377381/tree?tab=general) which I was surprised didn't get acted on, so I checked his chat history which is mostly troll - let alone the deleted messaged.

[image]

Comment: Right now, that user is suspended from chat

Comment: Well, it was Summer of Love, and the guy is obviously suffering from a particularly nasty form of Tourette's syndrome, so...

Comment: @bfavaretto, for ~40 more minutes, yup. *That* will show him.

Comment: A 30 minute ban, when the person isn't online anyway is hardly much of a dis-incentive.

Comment: @Abizern Well, this post pretty much devalues what SO is trying to do, which is to prevent this kind of stuff from being seen. Oh well, though, I guess its better to make it known and get it fixed than to leave it alone. Still, I might have used a small helping of blur :)

Comment: *"This user has been temporarily suspended by a moderator and cannot chat for 29 days."*

Comment: Waiting for a "Why am I no longer allowed to chat?" in 3...2...

Comment: @PhillipSchmidt: Better than nobody seeing it is everyone seeing that *it's not tolerated.*

Comment: @DavidRobinson Hence the second part of my comment, notably the suggestion of keeping the content but blurring the explitives :)